# Post collection of objects to server

Tags: c#, http, post

I am totally new to this.. I want to send a collection (List) with objects via a POST call a server.
I have managed to send a regular string but how do I do with a List?

```
request.Method = "POST";
string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";       
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;     
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();     
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);   
dataStream.Close();

WebResponse response = null;
   try
   {
     response = request.GetResponse();
     dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

     string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

     reader.Close();
     dataStream.Close();
      response.Close();
   }
   catch (WebException)
   {
       labelShowMessage.Text = "";   
   }
```

Comment: That totally depends on the list format the server expects.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: That you need to know in what format the server expects lists.

Comment: Ok, so what formats are there? This differ from when you sending text?

Comment: There are as many formats as there are programmers. Remember you're sending key-value pairs. If it's PHP, a list may look like `key[]=value&key[]=value`, while in ASP.NET it'll look like `key=value&key=value`, others may expect `key=value,value`. It becomes even more interesting if you want to exchange objects, for example `key[0].property=value&key[1].property=value`. If the script expects the value to be encoded in a certain format, say, JSON, you'll have to do so. And so on. You really should ask the creator of the script that parses your request.

Comment: Ok, if the server side has a POST with: public HttpResponseMessage Post(List<StoreItem> storeItems), how can I make this POST?